# Opening a bootstrap modal with leafletsjs

Tags: jquery, leaflet, bootstrap-modal

I'm using a map and leafletjs, in the map i have a few markers, when the user clicks a marker a bootstrap modal should show up with a highcharts chart.
something like this: http://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons-example.html  but with a modal.
How i can achieve this?

It would be better if angularjs is used.

i made a quick fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kLLcetev/

This is the code where is supposed to open the modal:

```
  function markerFunction(){
        for (var i in markers){
            var markerID = markers[i].options.title;

                markers[i].openPopup();

        $("#Modal").modal("show"); 
        $("#Modal").modal("open");
        $("#Modal").modal();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried opening the modal in the click event of the marker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do this with Angular, UI-Bootstrap is a very nice option:

> Bootstrap components written in pure AngularJS by the AngularUI Team

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Inject the `ui-bootstrap` module into your app and `$uibModal` service into your controller:

```
angular.module('app', [
    'ui.bootstrap'
])

angular.module('app').controller('leaflet', [
             '$uibModal',
    function ($uibModal) {

    }
])
```

Opening the modal in a Leaflet click event:

```
new L.Marker([n, n]).on('click', function () {
    $uibModal.open({
        template: '<div highchart></div>',
    })
})
```

A simple Highcharts directive:

```
angular.module('app').directive('highchart', [
    function () {
        return {
            link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
                $(element[0]).highcharts(...)
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Here's a demo on Plunker: http://embed.plnkr.co/ZiHMFC/preview

Answer (score 2):

I would think that watching the click event, then creating the modal html on demand would work, like below.

```
var markerGroup = L.featureGroup;
markerGroup.addTo(map)
//For each marker, .addTo(markerGroup)
markerGroup.on('click', function (event) {
    var modalDiv = "<div class='modal fade'.... [(docs)][1]
    $(modalDiv).modal({})
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set up the modal at the beginning and not show it by using

`$("#Modal").modal({show:false});`

Then bind to each marker's click event and show the modal in the called function.

```
for (var i in markers){
    var markerID = markers[i].options.title;
    markers[i].openPopup();
    markers[i].on('click', function() {
        $("#Modal").modal("show"); 
    });
}
```

Live example here: http://jsfiddle.net/0x7v8gkd/

Comment: There are, of course, other ways to structure the code but this preserves much of your existing code.

Comment: it wil be efficient when the number of markers is nearby 100?